# Java How To Read A Specific Line

Tags: java, authentication, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I want help myself, I made a file that would create a user file, because I plan on making a game. It has a login that writes the Login name, the Display name, and the Password. It writes it out to a file named after the Login Name.

Now I wish to make a login script as well, using java. I want to know, specifically, how to read the line and the already entered password.

I have it so that when it creates the file, it saves the password twice, once as "playerPass" and once as "currPass" so that, if one planned to change the password (which I will use from the login script), then the currPass would be read as the correct password using the playerPass variable. Anyway, I would like for it to use BufferedReader and FileReader to read the line indicating the password and the current password so that one may log in.

Can someone help me out a lot with this? I am still, to a point, novice.

PS. I can tweak code, I just need a little explanation on HOW TO code it lol.

Variables:

```
playerLogName
playerName
playerPass
currPass
```

File names:

```
Login.java
CharacterFileCreator.java
```

MADE AN ADDITION, got it half working, but it locks up (using Dr. Java) after I enter password, regardless of what I do, incorrect or correct, *and the System.out.println() never executes, even if the password is incorrect.* Check it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Login {

  public static void LogIn(){
    boolean loggedIn = false;
    loggedIn = true;
    System.out.println("You are now logged in!");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    System.out.println("What is your login name?");
    Scanner charLogName = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerLogName = charLogName.nextLine();
    boolean charFileFound = false;
    BufferedReader characterfile = null;

    try {
      characterfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./game/characters/" + playerLogName + ".txt"));
      charFileFound = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fileex1) {}
    if(charFileFound == false){
      System.out.println("Login name does not exist!");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println(playerLogName + ": is your username, what is your password?");
      Scanner charPassword = new Scanner(System.in);
      String playerPass = charPassword.nextLine();
      String line = "";
      String token = "";
      String token2 = "";
      int ReadMode = 0;
      try {
        line = characterfile.readLine();
      } catch (IOException ioexception) {
        System.out.println(playerLogName + ": error loading file.");
      }
      while (line != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        int spot = line.indexOf("=");
        if (spot > -1) {
          token = line.substring(0, spot);
          token = token.trim();
          token2 = line.substring(spot + 1);
          token2 = token2.trim();
          switch (ReadMode) {
            case 1:
              if (token.equals("character-password")) {
              if (playerPass.equals(token2)) {
                LogIn();
              } else {
                System.out.println("You entered an incorrect password!");
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        }            else {
          if(line.equals("[ACCOUNT]")) {
            ReadMode = 1;
          }
          else if(line.equals("[EOF]")) {
            try {
              characterfile.close();
            } catch (IOException ioexception) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

SAMPLE FILE:

```
[ACCOUNT]
character-loginname = SampleFile
character-password = samplepassword
[EOF]
```

Comment: Show a sample file in your question.

Comment: *"sorry guys, its 4:15am here haha."*  Not a valid excuse.  If you are put in a position that you have to give excuses for a poor question, that is a good sign that you should either not be asking the question, or should delay asking it until you are fit to do so. -1

Comment: Im 17, im still a kid, I have an excellent "excuse", and that "excuse" was for the "brainfart" i had! Wasnt for anything else, i am NEW at it, and I need help, the point of asking QUESTIONS, is to GET HELP, if you dont know something, you dont, i had been looking for awhile for a fix, well, a few hours, but im not gonna sit up for 12hrs looking on how to fix something like that. ** And yes, being up for 34 hrs straight is a valid excuse, thank you very much.

Comment: @Mauricio, I believe the info i showed was enough >.>, and im sure most people would agree with me.

Comment: @Daniel To be honest, I am younger than you and I don't see that as a good *excuse* either. I have only been programming in Java for about 6 months as well. Being up for 34 hours straight is probably a contributing factor as well - you, like anyone, obviously can't think straight and as a result, you may be overlooking/missing a simple error in your program, AND asking questions when you are not focussed. Surely something like "pass" would come to your mind before "brainfart"? It is not good to argue either, Andrew and Mauricio are making valid points and trying to help whilst ur being smart!

Comment: @Andy, there was no "helping" in anything they said. I may be somewhat new to coding, but just because I couldnt think of one WORD, doesn't mean I wasn't focused. Are you telling me that you don't have moments when you forget one simple word and can't think of it for a little while. EVERYONE gets problems like that, anyone who denies it is either a liar, or just doesn't remember.

@ Maur -- I understand now, I was thinking a little different then what you meant, you should have said it a little differently, I honestly don't know why I thought of it the way I did, but ill add one.

Comment: And The Edit I made, there was more helping in wat Mauricio said than Andrew, and the word I forgot was "variable" not "pass".

Comment: @Daniel No body is denying that everyone makes mistakes, and we're not saying that. In fact, I'll be the first to admit that I have blank moments quite often. However, what we are saying is that, you shouldn't be asking questions and making posts when you obviously aren't thinking straight at that moment in time. If this site was aimed at "kids" maybe you'd have a valid excuse, but seeing as though your choosing to use the website not aimed at immature children then it's your responsibility to make sure what you post is appropriate and adult like...

Comment: Maybe what Andrew put wasn't helpful, but I doubt it was supposed to be. He was making a point; a valid one at that! Have you noticed how I am now the only one posting? That is because you're arguing and trying to prove Andrew and Mauricio wrong just because you don't agree with what they have said, most likely because it is against you, even though what they have said is completely valid. I could go on for hours talking about what you've done wrong, but you've got to understand it is in your best interest to ask politely and correctly, not there's to answer!

Comment: Also, when programming you will learn that, for anybody, it is necessary to take regular breaks and let your mind rest, especially when you encounter problems. If you start coding for extended periods without taking a break and thinking about something else; - coming back with a fresh mind, it is easy to start getting lost and make simple mistakes etc.

Comment: My brother doesnt, and he could outcode anyone I know, the only way to become better than him is to BE like him, he takes breaks about every 7hrs, i was only coding for 5hrs, and it wasnt just on that, i was basically screwin around. And the only thing i couldnt remember was the word Variable, so why should that make me stop asking a question? Im sure everyone else who has read this read that and understood what I meant, I mean, if it were something else, I would understand, but that is completely different. -- and about andrew, he didnt have to be an ass about it, he couldve said it nicer.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to use a properties file! You can still give it any file extension you want and even encrypt it if you so wish, but by using the Properties object you can get or set any property regardless of the line number!

Look here for an example: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html

UPDATE: I have spotted your problem - you are never reading the next line of the file in your  `while` loop, so you would probably find that if you put `System.out.println(line);` somewhere inside of the loop it would just keep displaying "[ACCOUNT]" - the first line of your file!

To solve this problem, I may be inclined to put the entire loop in a `try` `catch` statement and change the condition to `while((line = characterfile.readLine()) != null)`. That way, every loop uses the next line, but it could be problematic in terms of  catching exceptions, depending on the situation.

Alternatively, you could add `line = characterfile.readLine();` after you set `ReadMode` to 1 in your `if(line.equals("[ACCOUNT]"))` statement, and as an else statement when testing `if (token.equals("character-password"))`....

However, if you do follow my advice and use the `Properties` file you  will not be required to do any looping to get the character data as you can just call something like `password = propertyObject.getyProperty("password")` as the example link shows.

HTH

Comment: Andy, I will check into that, but I would still like a solution to my current issue before I do so, I elsewise, I don't learn from the mistakes I have already made, I just learn new things to avoid the mistakes. Awhile back I had experimented on a non-profit, non-hosted RuneScape Private Server, just for a little coding experience, anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't really help on a solution to your current issue with the information you have provided unfortunately. Your code looks okay to me, though I do wonder what you mean by "locks up", as your code doesn't seem to do much after the password has been checked - if you get the password wrong does the `System.out.println()` line execute, or do you receive any exceptions/errors anywhere?

Comment: no there is nothing after it, it just freezes, I have waited and nothing happens, I just have to recompile it so it stops trying to do whatever it is doing that makes it lock up.

Comment: Also, Ive made edits, instead of just switching from boolean loggedIn false - true, i made it do a void of switching it and showing a system message, however, still no avail towards incorrect/correct password.

Comment: Please see my edit. I think I've solved your problem... AND I hate to say it, but it's the type of simple problem you miss when you are tired and fail to do simple debugging!...

Comment: No, it is just something I didnt have knowledge of to be honest, not exactly a "mistake" more like an INCOMPETENT error, youll see that i am an honest person, I am not afraid to deny the truth of errors I make. Also, my brother said hed help me understand properties files better, he recoded it in a properties file for me, but imma change it, i dont want HIS work >.> help is different from "work" ill work with it but i wont, in all, keep it. But thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Daniel, I can't agree with you about the *incompentent error*, you had all the knowledge that you needed to solve your original problem. All you needed to do is see what was running and why the other things weren't using simple `System.out.println()` statements to print variables and simple debug messages; - no matter how good they are, every programmer will need to do this!

Comment: Anyway, about your brother - I used to be opinionated the same as you, and wouldn't directly use any code at all. However, think of it this way, your brother has shown you how to do it and in doing so has created a working example and is willing for you to use it, but now you are retyping the code and changing it in some way, which could make it larger, unnecessarily complex, means it takes more time or CPU, or even break it. To me, that's pointless. Fair enough if the code has licence constraints, but if not *why reinvent the wheel*, normally it has been written that way because...

Comment: it is the easiest and most appropriate way to do so, and by using existing code where you can it shows efficiency and intelligence, often preventing hassle etc., and to be brutally honest, I don't think any reason for not following this advice will change my mind, from a programmer's point of view. Anyway, you're welcome and I hope you have learnt a lot from this question (you should have) - I recommend you accept my answer to maintain your reputation etc.